# EmberJS and REST

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have an ember-data model `post`.

```
import DS from "ember-data";

var attr = DS.attr,
    belongsTo = DS.belongsTo,
    hasMany = DS.hasMany;

Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: attr('string'),
  url: attr('string'),
  text: attr('string'),
  userId: attr('number'),
  createdAt: attr('date'),
  updatedAt: attr('date'),
  user: belongsTo('user', async: true),
  comments: hasMany('comment', async: true),
  comments_length: attr('number')
});

export default Post;
```

It gets data from `/api/posts`.
Also, I have comments and when comment is added, post is updated.
I can get last updated posts at `/api/posts/last_updated`.
How to do this properly at EmberJS?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @givanse I don't know how to do this in good way. No I have another model `LastCommentedPost` with another adapter:

http://pastebin.com/prGuCZ5W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [ember-data-actions](https://github.com/davewasmer/ember-data-actions) for this. It's a good solution, but not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using query params to do that.

You could do something like

```
store.find('post',{last_updated: true}).then(function(promiseResult){//...});
```

Also depending on your `ember-data` version, you might need to use `query` instead of `find`, because the API changed recently

This way your backend would expect a query like `/api/posts?last_updated=true`